# How to convert spanish string to unicode to pass in json, PHP?

Tags: php, json, unicode

I have a string categoría in PHP variable that I need to convert in unicode and pass in json. Is htmlentities the correct way to do so? If not then what is the standard way to convert it in unicode and pass in json, in PHP?

Comment: If you're using php 5.5 take a look at UConverter of the Intl extension:http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.uconverter.php you do need utf8, do you?

Comment: Which encoding does the input have, and which encoding do you want to output to have (Unicode is *not* an encoding)?